# AD User list from certain OU's

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to print users of only certain OUs in my company AD.
So far I've come up with this:

```
string groupName = "Domain Users";
string domainName = "domain";

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

if (grp != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
    }


    grp.Dispose();
    ctx.Dispose();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The problem is that it prints every user and not a specific OU like "Employees" or "Students".

How do I add a parameter to specify 1 or 2 OU's that it should cycle through instead of a group?

Comment: You desired OU is a group? If yes, why are you searching in `Domain Users` instead of your desired groups?

Comment: trying to reach a diffrent result that i have right now, cause iam seaching in groups but i wanted to divde the "domain users" into seperate "containers", the OU's they are in currently are "employess and students"..
if that makes sence :)

Comment: how do you specify the type `Employee` or `Student` is it a property in the `Principal`?

Comment: The Employees and students are members of "Employees-Security", "Employees-Security" groups, but i want to export them to a DB. eg. there can be certain students that you dont want to export, and only choose certain OU's.

Comment: so what iam really after, is a method to search for OU names instead of groups :)

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft okay I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit your search to a single OU / container, you can just *bind* to that using another `PrincipalContext` constructor:

```
string groupName = "Domain Users";
string domainName = "domain";
string ouName = "CN=Users,DC=yourcompany,DC=com";

// bind to the specified container you want
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, ouName);
```

Then, of course, you're **only** searching in that `CN=Users` container - no where else.

Comment: This is what i am looking after.
before hand, sorry iam not a Pro programmer..
how do i implement this if i do it just as you described and nothing more it throws an referral exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code exactly so this is pseudocode.

When you have some property e.g. a string to specify the type then use `Where`:

```
 var groupName = "Student";
 foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false).Where(princ => princ.OUName.Equals(groupName))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
 }
```

Or is it some kind of inheritance then `OfType` can be used:

```
 foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false).OfType<Student>())
 {
     Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching the entire Domain, and "Domain Users" is probably not the OU you would wan´t, change the name of the variable and add:

```
string domainName = "Domain Users";
string groupName = "Students";
```

Then add the OU to your PrincipalContext:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, groupName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my Application.

This might be a bit overkill for you, but i think it mostly fits your needs.

```
public static void DoStuff(UserPrincipal princ) {

        var allDomains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast<Domain>();

        var allSearcher = allDomains.Select(domain => {
          var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain.Name));
          searcher.Filter = $"(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=*{princ.SamAccountName}*)))";
          return searcher;
        });

        var directoryEntriesFound =
          allSearcher.SelectMany(searcher =>
            searcher.FindAll()
              .Cast<SearchResult>()
              .Select(result => result.GetDirectoryEntry()));

        var memberOf = directoryEntriesFound.Select(entry => {
          using (entry) {
            return new {
              Name = entry.Name,
              GroupName = ((object[])entry.Properties["MemberOf"].Value)
                .Select(obj => obj.ToString())
            };
          }
        }
          );

        var result1 = new List<string>();
        foreach (var member in memberOf) {
          if(member.GroupName.Contains("Student") )
            Console.WriteLine(princ.SamAccountName + " is Student");
          if (member.GroupName.Contains("Employee"))
            Console.WriteLine(princ.SamAccountName + " is Employee");

        }


      }
```

Just call this  in your `foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))`